# Tools for qualitative analysis of non-autonomous ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

We consider a non-autonomous ODE defined on the plane $\mathbf{R}^2$, of the form
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x' &=& y - x \\
y' &=& \varphi(t,x,y). 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for some regular function $\varphi: \mathbf{R}^3 \to \mathbf{R}$.

We focus on a particular solution $(x,y): \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}^2$, which we hope to show lies in the domain $\Omega = \{ y < x \}$ for all time. In the situation I am considering a linearisation argument confirms this for large negative and positive times: there is $T > 0$ so that
\begin{equation}
y(t) < x(t) \text{ for all $\lvert t \rvert > T$}. 
\end{equation}

The trouble lies with the intermediate range $[-T,T]$: unfortunately $\varphi$ does not have a sign on $\partial \Omega = \{ y = x \}$.  Moreover, no obvious monotone quantities are available.

**Question.** What tools are available to show that a particular solution has $y(t) < x(t)$ for all $t \in [-T,T]$?

Comment: Given that at the level generality you are describing the problem, there certain exist solutions that traverse across the boundary $\{y = x\}$, I don't think you can expect any "general tools" to work. // Furthermore, when you say there are no "obvious" monotone quantities available, remember that obvious is in the eye of the beholder. It would be a tiny bit more productive for you to list the type of monotone quantities your tried. Maybe someone else spots something that you missed.

Comment: @WillieWong That's a totally fair comment. I purposely posted a general version in the hopes that some tricks might be available. Underlying this was the thought thtasecond equation is non-autonomous. That and maybe the fact that the $(x,y) \in \Omega$ for large positive and negative time.